# ¿Que debe de contener un Código QR internamente para que al ser leído por un lector registre la asistencia de un Usuario dentro de una Tabla en Apex?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, apex, consultar

El objetivo es realizar una aplicación móvil de asistencias por código QR pero lo que no me queda claro es que debe contener ese Código QR internamente para que pueda realizar registro de la asistencia de un usuario

**Mi finalidad es la siguiente:** Al momento de que el usuario entre ala Aplicación e Inicie sesión y presione el botón de escanear le abra el lector de QR y al pasar el lector sobre el código le Registre la Asistencia ( La Fecha y Hora de Entrada o Salida de ese usuario) al leer dicho código QR en la tabla de asistencias acorde ala Sesión iniciada.

El sistema web ya esta realizado en Oracle Apex pero solamente ase falta implementar esa función de la aplicación móvil para llevar el control de los registros sobre las asistencias de los usuarios y es donde me surge esa duda.

De antemano agradezco mucho su atención a todos y espero puedan ayudarme a resolver esa duda. Por Favor. Gracias..

**Nota:** Adjunto captura de la Tabla donde los campos resaltados almacenaran las horas de entrada y salida al momento de que el usuario autenticado haga el escaneo del QR Mencionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia, entre el lector de codigo de barra y Oracle APEX no hay un codigo de ejecucion (programa) de por medio?

Comment: Asta el momento no. Eh pensado en implementar una API mas adelante y un favor Podrías ser un poco mas especifico sobre el termino programa de por medio para saber a que te refieres por favor.

Pero como te comento me quede con esa duda sobre que debe de contener mi QR Internamente para que pueda hacer la función que menciono por favor.

Gracias y Saludos...

Salufos y Bendicones

Comment: osea el codigo QR solo debe tener los datos suficiente para identificar que esa persona es un empleado activo de la empresa; pero en tu software necesitas que algo haga esa validacion y capture los datos minimos que se requieren para grabar la asistencia .....

Comment: a lo mejor necesitar capturar la hora ... y el codigo QR no te dara esa informacion el codigo QR se espera sea Fijo....

Comment: elcodigo QR puede tener informacion como nombre, numero de empleado estructura a la que pertenece o datos personales como tipo de sangre etc ....

Comment: esos datos tambien deberian ser recuperables de tu base de datos si el codigo QR no los tiene usando el id de empleado que si debe estar en el codigo QR

Comment: Entiendo esa parte bro de que mi QR debe de Tener Algún dato que valide que lo que yo envió coincide con algún registro existente dentro de la base de datos.

Pero ahora mi pregunta es como traer esa información o insertarla en el QR para que al ser enviada coincidan con la Data-base.

De casualidad no tendrás algún ejemplo que me pudieses compartir por favor o habría alguna manera de contactarte ya que soy nuevo en este tema bro y la verdad se me esta dificultando.

De antemano agradezco mucho tu apoyo y atención y que dios te bendiga bro.

Comment: No en realidad eso es parte de la investigacion o estudio que debes hacer para desarrollar tu sistema de registro de asistencia, en el sitio no brindamos ejemplos... nosotros por ejemplo te podemos ayudar si hay algun problema en tu codigo que arroje algun error en el que estas trabajo y no sabes resolver... basado en programacion.

Comment: No te preocupes amigo.
Agradezco mucho tu atención y en verdad gracias por el apoyo.

Que Dios Te Bendiga Bro.